# Silverlight 4 Feb 2011 Update and Network Latency

Tags: silverlight, networking, silverlight-4.0

Microsoft released an update for the Silverlight runtime on Feb 14th 2011 called *GDR3* or version *4.0.60129.0*.

[More Info](http://timheuer.com/blog/archive/2011/02/14/silverlight-february-2011-update-gdr3.aspx)

They have updated the "HTTP stack" to improve latency ([KB article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2505882)).

**Does this improvement only apply to the built-in Silverlight HTTP stack?**

What I mean is do I have to do something like this to see this improvement?:

```
System.Net.WebRequest.RegisterPrefix("http://", System.Net.Browser.WebRequestCreator.ClientHttp);
```

Comment: +1 Good question, MS should speak more plainly about which stack. It seems most likely to be the client stack since I doubt the silverlight runtime has much say in how the browser stack works. However there still a chance that the improvement is in how silverlight uses the existing browser stack.

Comment: There was mention of the use of "background threads" improving networking perf in the upcoming Silverlight 5. I wonder if this that feature delivered early?  I suppose I could imagine some type improvements to the *browser* stack's interaction with the SL runtime with better use of threads, but "90%"?